# Using JS How to call click function once only which will be equivalent to .one jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello could someone help me? I'm having trouble transforming this part of my code to JS:

```
$(".custom-select-trigger").on("click", function() {
  $('html').one('click',function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
  $(this).parents(".custom-select").toggleClass("opened");
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

I have it so far:

```
  const customSelectTrigger = document.querySelector(".custom-select-trigger");
  const customSelect = document.querySelector(".custom-select");
  function showOptions(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    customSelect.classList.toggle("opened");
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```

but I'm not able to do this part for javascript:

```
  $('html').one('click',function() {
    $(".custom-select").removeClass("opened");
  });
```

Comment: `addEventListener` has a `once` option; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working code for to remove class `opened` from your custom select when you press anywhere in the DOM.

You need to use JS [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and `click` function to do this.

To remove class from an element we can use [.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)  function and getting the `classList` of your element by `querySelector` which will `.custom-select`

**Edit**: If you just want to use the click function once only per *DOM* load. Then setting setting the args `{ once: true }` will only invoke the function once.

I have recreated your example and its working.

Run snippet below.

```js
//Getting HTML element
const htmlElement = document.querySelector("html");
 
//Getting element where to remove the class from
const customSelect = document.querySelector(".custom-select");

//Adding eventlistener to remove class opened from classList
htmlElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  customSelect.classList.remove("opened");
  console.log('Class Removed')
  e.preventDefault();
 },{ once: true });
```

```css
.opened {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<h3>
  Click anywhere on the DOM to remove class from Custom select
</h3>

<div class="custom-select opened">
  My Custom Select
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: That's not handling the `one` part of the question

Comment: @Ben Answer updated to invoke the function once only.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping can u helpme with this question bro? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856003/find-val-jquery-to-js